# How to apply a dictionary to an array to have it sort properly?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, key

This is in a swift playground and the final objective is to get the dictionary to be sorted using the `Months: [String]` array. Here is what the code looks like right now:

```
Class YearlyTemps { 
    var Months: [String] = ["January", "February"...]
    var Temperatures: [String,(temp1: Int, temp2: Int)] = [:]     
    func SetMonthlyTemps(month: String, temp1: Int, temp2: Int) -> Void { 
        Temps [month] = (low, high)
    } 
    func ShowResult() -> Void {
        for key in Temps.key{
            print(key)
        }
        for values in Temps.value{
            print(values)
        }
    }
}
```

It currently displays the dictionary as:

```
December
November
January

(23, 40)
(20, 55)
(-2, 34)
```

With no real order to it. I need it to be like this in order (January-December with temps on same line):

```
January (-2, 34)    
November (20, 55)    
December (23, 40)
```

I've tried to push the dictionary into an array with no luck as of yet. And I'm not sure if I should have default values in the Months array or not or if that should be populated in the SetMonthlyTemps function.

Comment: `[String,(temp1: Int, temp2: Int)]`  it is not a valid syntax for declaring a dictionary. Besides that it is Swift convention to name your vars and methods starting with a lowercase letter. And it should `class` instead of `Class`. Temps it is not even declared in your "Class" and (low, high) it is also undeclared.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the key-value pairs with

```
for entry in Temps {
    print("\(entry.key) \(entry.value)")
}
```

Also you can sort your dictionary the same way you would sort an array with `.sorted(by: )`. All in one it would give

```
for entry in Temps.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }) {
    print("\(entry.key) \(entry.value)")
}
```

Now since you want to sort by month as they are sorted in the year, you will need to tell your code what it means. The easiest way is, instead of using `String` variables for your months, define them using an `enum` type. Moreover, if you chose `Int` as `rawValue` for your enum they will automatically be ordered in the way you define them in the enum. This will look like this:

```
enum Month: Int {
    case january
    case february
    case march
    ...
    case december
}
```

Then you simply need to change your `Temps` variable to be of type `[Month: (Int, Int)]` instead of `[String: (Int, Int)]`. Finally, you can simply use

```
for entry in Temps.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 }) {
    print("\(entry.key) \(entry.value)")
}
```

Finally I would recommend using lower case camelCase for your variable names.

Comment: This would sort it alphabetically not considering how the months are sorted in the year

Comment: Yes if you want to sort by year you can create an `enum` where each month has a `int` `rawValue` and then sort by `rawValue`. If you want to keep both the `String` name and an `Int` index, I would recommend using a `struct`

Comment: You would  still  need to sort it by the keys `sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })`

Comment: And you need to make the enum Hashable to use it as the Dictionary keys. `enum Month: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable, Comparable { case january, february, march, april, may, june, july, august, september, october, november, december var description: String { return Calendar.current.monthSymbols[hashValue] } static func <(lhs: Month, rhs: Month) -> Bool { return lhs.hashValue < rhs.hashValue } }`

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not have an order in swift along with many other languages. If you have an array with all the month names called `monthsArray`, I would iterate over that and use the value at each index as a key to get the values from the dictionary.

```
var monthsArray = ["January", "November", "December"]
var tempsDict: [String : (Int, Int)] = [:]

tempsDict["November"] = (11, 11)
tempsDict["January"] = (1, 1)
tempsDict["December"] = (12, 12)

for month in monthsArray {
    //Check to make sure dictionary has key
    if let temps = tempsDict[month] {
        print("\(month): \(temps)")
    }
}
```